# Magento 2 : Error While Installing

Tags: magento2, installation, php-5.4

I want to install magento 2 on Ubuntu. I upgrade my PHP version to 7.1.3 and when I execute command to check php version I am getting below output:

> PHP 7.1.3-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) (built: Mar 25 2017 14:24:10) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.1.3-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

When I am trying to install Magento 2.1.x, I am gettig php version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21.

Please check below screenshots for referance.

[image]
and because of this i am unable to proceed.

Comment: Are you incorrectly checking the PHP version of the Server? *not* your `localhost` Those modules look like the ones often missing on WAMP.

Comment: I am checking on my localhost.. open cmd and execute commang php -v

Comment: Have you try to check php version with phpinfo() in your server? What it show to you?

Comment: It showing 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21

Comment: Please restart your apache server

Comment: You should install missing extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For upgrading PHP version you can go through following steps
Run the following command if you are using linux:

```
For PHP 5.5, PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.0:

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php

For PHP 5.4 (Deprecated, upgrade at least to PHP 5.5):

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable

For PHP 5.5 (Deprecated, use ppa:ondrej/php):

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php5

For PHP 5.6 (Deprecated, use ppa:ondrej/php):

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6

sudo apt-get update
```

If you are WAMP user then refer following link
https://john-dugan.com/upgrade-php-wamp/

**Missing extension error**

For any missing extension you just need to go php.ini and remove find that extension from the file and remove the semicolon from that line Or if you are on local machine then you can click on wamp,xamp and mamp icon. Go to PHP extensions – > find the missing extension and click on it then restart the server. Following screenshot show how we can do it using wamp.

[image]

**INSTALL EXTENSION**

```
 sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl
 sudo apt-get install php7.0-xsl
```

If you have already upgrade then please run following commnad and restart apache:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

To switch from 5.5 to 7

```
 $ sudo a2dismod php5.5 
 $ sudo a2enmod php7.1 
 $ sudo service apache2
 restart
```